# SDL Tridion Workflow Companion for IPad

Tags: workflow

I just tried to install the workflow companion for iPad which is on the [SDL Tridion World](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/workflowcompanion.aspx) site, and iTunes tell me it is not on the US or UK iTunes stores. Can anyone tell me how to download this, and if not where I might be able to get the source code from?

The download code on SDL Tridion World seems only to have the server component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it has been removed from the App Store for some reason:  http://www.appannie.com/app/ios/tridion-workflow-companion/.

It was described as "Initial release of the Workflow Companion app", so I guess that there may be an updated version coming.  You may have to contact [Peter](http://www.linkedin.com/in/beemster) directly.

Comment: Yes, it seems to have been removed. I tracked down an old copy I had, and am trying to locate the source code